# Creating user accounts

Tags: java, validation, controller, javafx

I have a method which allows to create user account. It contains some conditions to control empty fields, wrong format of email, weak password, etc.

```
  errorSet = false;

    @FXML
    private void createAccount() throws IOException {

        if (!lastNameField.getText().isEmpty() && !firstNameField.getText().isEmpty() && userRole.getValue() != null && !emailField.getText().isEmpty() && !passwordField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            if (SharedRegexController.isEmailSyntax(emailField.getText()) && SharedRegexController.isValidateEmail(emailField.getText())) {
                if (passwordField.getText().length() > StaticDigit.USER_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH) {
                    if (passwordField.getText().matches(".*[a-z]*.") && passwordField.getText().matches(".*[A-Z].*") && passwordField.getText().matches(".*[1-9]*.")) {
                        if (termsAgreementCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                            //Get values from text fields
                            String lastNameValue = lastNameField.getText().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
                            String firstNameValue = firstNameField.getText().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
                            String userRoleValue = (String) userRole.getValue();
                            String emailValue = emailField.getText().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
                            //Encrypt password
                            String passwordValue = Encapsulation.encrypt(passwordField.getText());
                            //Process adding operation
                            entrepreneur = new EntrepreneurModel(lastNameValue, firstNameValue, userRoleValue, emailValue, passwordValue, DateService.getLocalDate(), userAccountImageFile);
                            process();                            
                        } else {
                            termsPopOver = new PopOver();
                            Label acceptTerms = new Label(SignUpBundle.getAcceptTermsText());
                            acceptTerms.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontPosture.REGULAR, 13));
                            acceptTerms.setPadding(new Insets(5));
                            termsPopOver.setContentNode(new HBox(acceptTerms));
                            termsPopOver.show(termsAgreementCheckBox);
                        }
                    } else {
                        pinError();
                    }
                } else {
                    pinError();
                }
            } else {
                pinError();
            }

        } else {
            pinError();
        }

    }
```

`PinError()` is a method that display errors of user. This method should be called only one time:

```
 private void pinError() {

        if (!errorSet) {

            SharedErrorController.setEmptyValueError(firstNameField, SignUpBundle.getFirstNameErrorProvider());

            SharedErrorController.setEmptyValueError(lastNameField, SignUpBundle.getLastNameErrorProvider());

            SharedErrorController.setEmptyValueError(userRole, SignUpBundle.getRoleErrorProvider());

            SharedErrorController.setEmptyValueError(emailField, SignUpBundle.getEmailErrorProvider());

            SharedErrorController.setEmptyValueError(passwordField, SignUpBundle.getPasswordErrorProvider());

            SharedErrorController.setUnvalidateEmail(emailField, SignUpBundle.getUnvalidateEmail());

            SharedErrorController.setSmallPassword(passwordField, SignUpBundle.getSmallPassword());

            SharedErrorController.setUnvalidatePassword(passwordField, SignUpBundle.getUnvalidatePassword());

            SharedErrorController.setWeakPassword(passwordField, SignUpBundle.getWeakPassword());

            errorSet = true;
        }

    }
```

I want to convert `if`-`else` condition blocks to one condition like this:

```
@FXML
    private void createAccount() throws IOException {
     if(one_condition){ 
     }else{ 
      pinError()
     };
}
```

Hence I am not sure which way is better to choose, and considering my use case. Any help/recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I see that this code violates some OOP principals, [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for instance where a function should have one and only responsibility where this latter does more.

So if I were in your shoes I would split each condition to a function and call 'em all once, so it would be something like this:

```
private boolean checkFullName(...){
   return !lastNameField.getText().isEmpty() &&
          !firstNameField.getText().isEmpty() && 
          userRole.getValue() != null && 
          !emailField.getText().isEmpty() && 
          !passwordField.getText().isEmpty()
}

private boolean checkPassword(...){
...
}


@FXML
private void createAccount() throws IOException {
if (checkFullName() && checkPassword() && ...){
   ...
else{
   pinError()
    }
  }
}
```

Does this work? would like to hear your thoughts and feedback...

Comment: @IlyesSudo ,if I use your sample method ,I will fall in twice calls when I will be in errors handling phase.

Answer (score 0):

> Code review is for asking review on working code. To ask for a solution to your problem you should consider https://stackoverflow.com/.

Anyway. If what you want is to convert `if` - `else` condition to one condition, then move all the logic to one method that contains all the validation:

```
private void createAccount() throws IOException {
    if ( isValid() ) {
        EntrepreneurModel model = // ...
        process(model);
    } else {
        pinError();
    }
}

private boolean isValid() {
    if (...) {
        if (...) {
            if (...) {
                if (...) {
                    if (termsAgreementCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                        return true;                      
                    } else {
                        // ...                           
                        termsPopOver.show(termsAgreementCheckBox);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this will left you with mixed responsibilities as said by @llyeSudo plus a form where everything will be pinned for only one invalid field plus a deep nesting of `if`.

If you want to improve your code you may consider to have a `View` class to represent your form and a `Validator` that can validate this `View`. The `View` is querried to return all fields value or states. The `Validator` regroup all the validation rules and return one object that contains all the invalid fields. With those elements you can have a flow that is quite clear and avoid all the nested `if`.

```
private final UserAccountValidator validator = new UserAccountValidator();

public void create(UserAccountForm form) {
    Violations violations = validator.validate(form);
    if ( !violations.isEmpty() ) {
        show(violations); // Improved pinError()
    } else if ( !form.isTermsAgreementSelected() ) {
        form.setTermsAgreementVisible(true); // termsPopover.show()
    } else {
        process(form);
    }
}
```

--

You can find my solution on https://github.com/gervaisb/stackexchange-codereview/blob/q192870/src/main/java/q192870/UserAccountController.java

Comment: ,my code is working nice,I asked for improve the code by minimize the if-else conditions blocks in case of multiple operations.

Comment: @XlintXms yes, sorry. My message was not really clear. That's also why I provided an answer. If you don't want to pin detailed errors, your validator can return a `boolean`